# Outlook plugin to transform an hashtag in a link

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

In outlook, I need to parse the email content and transform a hashtag (#) into a link. Can I use C# to develop the ad-don?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can develop a VSTO based add-in in C#. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for getting started quickly. There are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. Word editor. The Inspector class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

Note, if you are interested in web add-ins, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio). In that case you must use JavaScript & HTML & CSS.